# two same html element have different dimentions

Tags: html

I have a premade table and trying to create a table like it and copied all classes from the previous table to newest table but `th` element in the new table has  different dimensions from the premade table.

I hope anyone can help me how I can solve this problem and have same exact `th`.

The premade table can be found in this link:
[premade table](https://bevedel.com/product/%D8%A2%DA%86%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3-value/)
and the exact part is:
[image]

and the new table with targeted `th` is:
[new table](https://bevedel.com/product/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA-1/)
[image]

**EDITED:**

To show the tab, please please from the dropdown select an option so that the tabs will be appeared and the table in it is available in inspect tool, like so:
[image]
Thank you

Comment: You have one slow loading website mate, that's one thing for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The table isn't even existing on the second link, but from looking at your images, I'd say that there is an issue with the elements font-size.

There aren't any special class selectors that would be relevant for styling your table and the only important CSS selector is `table tbody th`, so I'd assume that you made some mistakes in your HTML and it simply gets its font size from another CSS rule.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the table is created by jQuery, and not in direct html tags

Comment: Alright, can you please add the table back to the page at the second link so I can look at it using the developer tools?

Comment: I'm so sorry about late response. the table is visible if one option will selected from dropdown list. I inserted the picture for it for more clarification. Sorry for my bad english